# How To Prevent Scrolling Until All images are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

The scrollbar cannot scroll to the bottom due to some images not being loaded. How can I update the scrollbar when all the images are loaded? Appreciate no matter using JavaScript or jQuery.

```
<div class="scrollbar">
    <div class="thumb noSelect" unselectable="on"><div class="end">
</div></div></div>
<div class="viewport">
    <div class="overview">
        <ul class="pinkarrow">
            ......
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add `overflow: hidden` to scrollbar.

Then add following jQuery code to show your scrollbar when images are loaded:

```
(function($) {
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.scrollbar').css('overflow', 'auto');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Should I call the function when the body is loaded using like <body onload="showscroll()">?

Comment: There is already an event. `$(window).load();`. There is no need to add `<body onload="">`.